# Maps APIs: is it possible to geocode premise or building name in Malaysia

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Is it possible to geocode an address based on only building name in Malaysia?  I am using Maps APIs v3 geocode service with premier license but the query result always returns status:ZERO_RESULTS.

In http://maps.google.com.my/, premise search is working perfectly. Any idea if it's possible for Maps APIs?

Comment: Below is Google's official response:

The geocoding API is designed to convert a street address to the geographical location, or opposite.
A building name is not a complete street address. Geocoding API tries to find appropriate features for the incomplete street address, but it is not always possible.

In order to get accurate results, please specify a correct street address instead of a building name.

Answer (score -1):

It should be possible using the premise settings,  but it would depend on how robust the maps database is for Malaysia as an example:

```
var buildingName = "The Building Name";

geocoder.geocode( { 'premise' : buildingName }, function(results, status) {
...
}
```

Comment: That doesn't work for me. I can't find **premise** as a URL parameter in the documentation. Also, when I put this http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?premise=menara+ta+one in the browser, the result is "status" : "REQUEST_DENIED"