# Google Maps Geocode: unknow property premise

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, google-geocoding-api

I'm trying to add a marker on a building/premise on google maps, to do this I'm using the [Geocoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/). I tested it out by requesting an address and it worked perfectly.

```
var address = "...";
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
geocoder.geocode( {'address': address }, function(results, status) {
  if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
    var location_marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      map: map,
      position: results[0].geometry.location
    });
  }
});
```

According to the Geocoding API you can request a [building/premise](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#Types) by using the `premise` property, but when using `premise` I'm getting a JavaScript error `Uncaught InvalidValueError: unknown property premise`.

This is how I'm requesting the `premise` property:

```
var premise = "...";
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
geocoder.geocode( {'premise': premise }, function(results, status) {
  if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
    var location_marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      map: map,
      position: results[0].geometry.location
    });
  }
});
```

I followed the answer given for this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10024597/maps-apis-is-it-possible-to-geocode-premise-or-building-name-in-malaysia)

Not sure if anyone has had this problem before. Maybe there's another way to tackle this as well.

**UPDATE**

In case someone stumbles upon this question, to search businesses/places on Google Maps you can use the [Places Library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places). This returns objects with the business's address, location, name etc.

Hopefully this helps someone :)

Comment: Can you edit your question to show how you're using "premise"?

Comment: @Andy question updated, basically I'm using `premise` same as using the `address` property

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I there's some confusion here about what the Geocode API does. Read the API again for [**requests**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#GeocodingRequests).

The required parameters are `address` or `latlng` or `components`, and `sensor`.

The optional parameters are `bounds`, `language`, `region` and `components`.

`Premise` is one of the properties of the [**returned JSON data**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#Types). This means that you can't use it as a search parameter which is why the API is complaining.

The answer in that question to which you linked is *wrong*.

Hope this is helpful.

Comment: Okay thanks, is there any other way to put a marker on a premise? I can't seem to find any solution to this.

Comment: Either lat/lng or the full address?

Comment: Yeah I thought so...shame you can't mark and highlight a building same as when you search for it on google maps.